# Posting file and list of object in same request in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, postman, multipartform-data, webapi

can I set a post method to post image and list of object in the same time I have the following code it's logically working but I'm trying to test this request with postman

```
private ApplicationDbContext1 db = new ApplicationDbContext1();

[Route("api/save_BUY")]
        [HttpPost]
  public async Task< IHttpActionResult> save_BUY(IEnumerable<BY_table> BY_table,int id)
{
var BY_API = BY_table.Select(p => new BY_API
                    {

                        ITEM_CODE = p.ITEM_CODE,
                        ITEM_NAME = p.ITEM_NAME,
                        Unit = p.Unit,
                        Unit_Core = Convert.ToDecimal(p.Unit_Core),
                     
                    }).AsQueryable();
                    var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
                    var root = ctx.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
                    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
                  
                        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

                        foreach (var file in provider.FileData)
                        {
                            var name = file.Headers
                                .ContentDisposition
                                .FileName;

                            var localFileName = file.LocalFileName;
                            var filePath = Path.Combine(
                                root, "files", name);
byte[] fileBytes;
                using (var fs = new FileStream(
                PHOTO, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    fileBytes = new byte[fs.Length];
                    fs.Read(
                    fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                }
                var MASTER_BUY = db.MASTER_BUY.Where(x => x.int==id)
                {
                    MASTER_BUY.image= fileBytes;
                };
                
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Ok(BY_API);
            }
}
```

how can I make this request in postman to test it.
pleas help.

Comment: I know postman is capable of testing file uploads. Then it should be used as form data. I am not sure how that works for lists.

Answer (score 0):

You Can send Image Form of base64 String And Get String value from Client(Postman)
[Image to Base 64 String](https://www.base64-image.de/)
This is one Of Online tools for help you get base 64 string from file!

Comment: But I need it to be multipart file isn't that possible

Comment: See This https://dottutorials.net/dotnet-core-web-api-multipart-form-data-upload-file/

Comment: You Can send Array Of Files And Handle Request in Backend

Comment: How can I handle list of Json in backend

Comment: Send List Of string Base64 image And Handle its in backend     string[] Files; and Handle its in Action or methode